# What does 'Gulpin gargoyles' mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, idioms-in-context

> Well-I don't like saying the name if I can help it. No one does.
>
> Why not?
>
> Gulpin' gargoyles, Harry, people are still scared.

Comment: _Gulpin'_ is his way of pronouncing _gulping_.

Comment: This may not be obvious for those who haven't read the books, but this is Hagrid talking to Harry in "Harry Potter and the Philosopher's/Sorcerer's Stone".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Gulpin' gargoyles" is an *interjection* that the author invented. It's equivalent to saying, "For Christ's sake" or "My god".

This type of interjection always comes at the beginning of what you're saying, and is always a noun phrase. The noun phrase can be just about anything, but --as with this case-- it's usually somewhat related to the context, often includes *alliteration*, and frequently has an "-ing" adjective + noun. A gargoyle is a mythical creature you might expect in a Harry Potter book, the two "g" sounds make the alliteration, and the two words are an "-ing" adjective and a noun.

Another common feature of these interjections that's not present in this one is beginning with "Holy", like these lines from the TV series "Batman":

> Holy Las Vegas!
> Holy mechanical armies!
> Holy magic lantern!

Comment: My father used to say 'Jumping Jesus!'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I think I need to steal "Jumping Jesus".

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Not from my father, but I've heard "Jumpin' Jehosephat"

Comment: Kind of in the same vein as "Merlin's beard!"  Not a phrase anyone outside of the Potterverse would use, but you get the idea.